# Flutter, how to decrease width of DropdownButtonFormField active menu?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a DropdownButtonFormField inside a Container. When I click it, selections open and the width of that menu take all of the width of screen, because of container. I want to decrease the width of that menu.
[image]

Here, you see in picture I want to make it half of screen width.

my code:

```
Center(
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: _height * .02),
                height: _height * .066,
                width: _width * .9,
                child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  focusColor: Colors.black,
                  icon: Image.asset("assets/Arrow down.png"),
                  value: chosen,
                  dropdownColor: Colors.white,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5))),
                  items: dropdownList
                      .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                            child: Text(
                              e,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 13),
                            ),
                            value: e,
                          ))
                      .toList(),
                  onChanged: (String? value) {
                    setState(() {
                      chosen = value;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

To decrease the width of the active menu in a DropdownButtonFormField in Flutter, you can wrap it in a Container widget and specify the width for that container. Here's an example:

```
Container(
  width: 100,
 child: DropdownButtonFormField(
items: [
  DropdownMenuItem(
    child: Text('Option 1'),
    value: 'Option 1',
  ),
  DropdownMenuItem(
    child: Text('Option 2'),
    value: 'Option 2',
  ),
  DropdownMenuItem(
    child: Text('Option 3'),
    value: 'Option 3',
  ),
],
onChanged: (value) {
  // Handle the value change
  },
),
)
```

Comment: This does not change anything. If you meant to change the width of my main container in my code, it also changes my dropdown width. I want to only change active menu width.